# Why is my application receiving null instead boolean?

Tags: postgresql

I'm building a web app, and I noticed that one of my queries is returning a `null` where I expect a `boolean`. However the database is indicating it's actually returning a `boolean`.

I can see in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-boolean.html) that Postgres considers `NULL` to be an unknown boolean value. I'm confused why the `<=` operator would return `t`/`NULL` instead of `t`/`f` though.

```sql
select version();
```

| version |
| --- |
| PostgreSQL 13.13 (Debian 13.13-0+deb11u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit |

```sql
SELECT a.email_verified_at <= NOW() AS "emailVerified",
 pg_typeof(a.email_verified_at <= NOW()) AS "emailVerifiedType", 
 pg_typeof((a.email_verified_at <= NOW())::boolean) AS "emailVerifiedType2" 
FROM profiles AS p 
INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON p.id = a.profile_id;
```

| emailVerified | emailVerifiedType | emailVerifiedType2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | boolean | boolean |
| t | boolean | boolean |
|  | boolean | boolean |

How can I tell Postgres to return an explicit `t`/`f` to my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL has a three-valued logic: a boolean expression can be `TRUE`, `FALSE` or NULL (unknown). If you compare NULL (unknown) with any value, the result is NULL.

There are several ways to rewrite your comparison so that it returns `FALSE` if `email_verified_at` is a NULL value:

1. use `coalesce()`:

   ```
   coalesce(email_verified_at, 'infinity') <= current_timestamp
   ```
2. use an explicit NULL check

   ```
   email_verified_at IS NOT NULL AND email_verified_at <= current_timestamp
   ```

Another option would be to forbid NULL values in `email_verified_at` and store `infinity` if the e-mail address was never verified. This solution would simplify the comparison, but it may be undesirable for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `a.email_verified_at` is a nullable field. Comparison results involving `NULL` return `NULL`, which I didn't know. The solution is to check for `NULL` before comparing to `NOW()`:

```sql
SELECT a.email_verified_at <= NOW() AS "emailVerified",
(a.email_verified_at IS NOT NULL AND a.email_verified_at <= NOW()) AS "emailVerified2" 
FROM profiles AS p INNER JOIN
     accounts AS a ON p.id = a.profile_id;
```

| emailVerified | emailVerified2 |
| --- | --- |
|  | f |
| t | t |
|  | f |